# add column value to an existing csv file

Tags: powershell

I have a csv where I have to fill data into 2 existing column which are blank.

I was trying the below code but it is still blank

```
$v1='1.1.1.1'
$v2 = '2.2.2.2'

Import-Csv -Path "C:\New.csv" |
Select-Object *,@{Name='server_IP_address';Expression={$v1}},
@{Name="Server's Backup IP address";Expression={$v2}} | 
Export-Csv "C:\Csv\New_1.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Please let me know what I am missing here

Comment: "into 2 existing column" - then why _add_ 2 new ones?

Comment: I'd also recommend using headers that have no spaces or apostrophes. These will make it harder to process later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumed you used the correct names for the existing headers something like this should work

```
$v1 = '1.1.1.1'
$v2 = '2.2.2.2'

Import-Csv -Path "C:\New.csv" | 
    Select-Object -ExcludeProperty 'server_IP_address', "Server's Backup IP address" |
        Select-Object *, @{Name = 'server_IP_address'; Expression = { $v1 } },
            @{Name = "Server's Backup IP address"; Expression = { $v2 } } | 
                Export-Csv "C:\Csv\New_1.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Note that you can combine the two `Select-Object` calls (though if the column names don't change, a `ForEach-Object` solution with property assignments is simpler). If you combine them, the following point is moot: Unfortunately, a bug in Windows PowerShell (since fixed in PS Core) requires `-Property *` to be combined with `-ExcludeProperty` in order for the exclusion to take effect; try `[pscustomobject] @{ one=1; two=2 } | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty one` vs, `[pscustomobject] @{ one=1; two=2 } | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty one -Property *`

Answer (score 0):

> fill data into 2 existing columns

> I was trying the below code but it is still blank

Your code implies two things:

- `server_IP_address` and `Server's Backup IP address` are *not* the names of existing properties (columns), because trying to use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) to create [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) (`@{ Name=...; Expression=... }`) whose names are among the *existing* columns, selected with `*`, would *fail*, due to *duplicate* property names:

  - `Select-Object: The property cannot be processed because the property "<name>" already exists.`
- If your command did succeed, the implication is that you *added* two new columns to your CSV file.

---

To **fill or update *existing* columns**, the simplest approach is to use a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) with property assignments:

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\New.csv" |
  ForEach-Object { 
    $_.'server_IP_address' = $v1
    $_."Server's Backup IP address" = $v2
  } | Export-Csv "C:\Csv\New_1.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

---

To **add the desired values *under new column names***, stick with your existing approach, but *exclude the original properties (columns)* with `-ExcludeProperty` - though it is worth heeding [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo)'s recommendation to avoid spaces and `'` chars. in column names, so as not to complicate later programmatic processing.

Note:

- In the code below I'm assuming sample names `server_IP` and `server_BackupIP` as the original column names; adjust as needed.
- The new columns are added *after* the existing ones; to *prepend* them, use `-Property @{ ... }, @{ ... }, *`; to *insert* them between existing columns would require *explicitly enumerating* the column names and inserting the calculated properties (`@{ ... }`) as needed (avoiding the explicit enumeration would require a more complex, reflection-based approach via `ForEach-Object`).

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\New.csv" |
  Select-Object -ExcludeProperty server_IP, server_BackupIP -Property *,   
    @{ Name='server_IP_address';Expression={ $v1 } },
    @{ Name="Server's Backup IP address";Expression={ $v2 } } |
      Export-Csv "C:\Csv\New_1.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>As an aside: If you were to *only exclude* properties, without adding new ones, a bug in *Windows PowerShell* would still require explicitly specifying `-Property *` in order for `-ExcludeProperty` to take effect; this bug has been fixed in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*.</sup>

---

Note that **you could use the same technique to effectively *rename* existing columns** (while possibly also transforming their values), if you output (and possibly transform) their existing values from the `Expression` script blocks; e.g. `Expression = { $_.server_IP }`